# Good remote application logging/monitoring software

Tags: c#, java, c++, python, logging

I'm sure this has already been done, but Google isn't helping me - I'm getting swamped with answers for similar but different problems:

My boss has asked me to find or build a system that will log uses of our kiosk installations.  We build kiosks using java, native c++, c#, python and using things like Unity.  We saw another company we worked with using a simple system where a post call with data was logged on a remote site to be checked later.  The system allowed the application programmer to decide the contents of the message, and was able to allocate it to either debug or release according to the programmer's wishes.

An example of the log output might be:

```
[Debug] 28-11-2011 10:10:20 Kiosk1: Pulse
[Debug] 28-11-2011 10:10:25 Kiosk1: Button pressed
[Debug] 28-11-2011 10:10:45 Kiosk1: Widget used
[Debug] 28-11-2011 10:11:20 Kiosk1: Pulse
```

I looked at log4net/log4j, but that doesn't seem to be compatible with native c++ or python.  I'm probably mistaken there :).

Does anyone know of a system that works like this, or that will otherwise be suitable for logging from such diverse languages?  If not, I can write my own easily enough.  I just don't want to have to support it :)

Regards,
Steve

Comment: For some logging libraries for C++, see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/696321/440558

Comment: How frequent do you want the updates? Is this something for which you need current monitoring or on demand reporting? This would help in narrowing down your search and deciding what works for you; and would help others suggest relevant options.

Comment: Concurrent monitoring would be extremely useful.  We particularly want a pulse signal so that we can do things like email notifications if the system goes down.  This would probably need to be at least once every ten minutes, but not more that once a minute.  Other statistics could be queued for periodic updating.  It may be better to split the systems, I'm not sure.

Comment: I think with this you need to split it up into two requirements - systems monitoring (query every X minutes), in which case you query the device for updates, and then application reporting (which is your logging), which generally the application reports to a server.

Depending on connectivity at your kiosks, you have different options for each (SNMP traps vs. batch file uploads vs. end point client) - perhaps clarifying this will help further narrowing the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think what you're looking for is [SPLUNK](http://www.splunk.com/). This can parse almost every log and display it in a unified manner. It can listen to ports, read log files via polling and parses and indexes anything you throw at any point of time.

You can use this to set up you're own multi-language logging server/system. We've been using this and it seamlessly works in our distributed environment.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like what I wanted.  I'll try it out and report back!

Answer (score 1):

While writing a specialized logging backend to handle logging both locally and to the network is quite possible, I would advise against it. The reason being that network latency can be to long so it either stops your application, or logging messages can be queued up if using another process/thread to do the actual network pushing.

A much simpler solution is to use little script that is scheduled to run once or a couple of times per day, and that copies the log file(s) to the remote location.

Comment: well there might be situations where real-time log messages are a necessity(say web logs). In those cases, it is advisable to throw your messages to a local port which is always open and then re-direct these messages via another dedicated process to a remote server. This would not block the memory or the processing of the main process.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ I highly recommend [Poco logging](http://pocoproject.org/slides/110-Logging.pdf). It allows you to specify the formatting and log level/output using e.g. a properties file.

Comment: Exactly. We used log4cxx for a while, but there is a 64-bit linux bug that makes it segfault when closing the application.

Answer (score 0):

the [python logging library](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) that is included with python is quite similar to log4net, so if you are used to those, the other will be quite easy to understand, but they do not share code (as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

Use log4j/log4net with a socket appender or log remotely via rsyslog.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in something like [web beacons](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/W/Web_beacon.html).  I know it's not exactly what you're asking for, but you ought to think about it for the same reason that web developers do: it's good to know what users are doing.